# Do you need to commit a git submodule or just the gitmodules file

Tags: git, git-submodules

When you add a submodule to your git project - it adds a gitmodules file and pulls down the actual submodule and stores it in your project.

Do I need to commit the actual submodule that's pulled down or is it better to just commit the gitmodules file that describes the path to the submodule?

Comment: The `.gitmodules` file stores the stuff needed to `git clone` the *repository*. What's missing is *which commit to check out*. That information is stored in the superproject repository as a *gitlink* entry (`mode 160000`, in various Git outputs, vs `mode 100755` or `100644` for regular files, for instance). You must commit the gitlink entry. It's not clear to me whether that's what you mean by "the actual submodule".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will commit automatically both:

- the .gitmodule
- the **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** (special entry in the index of the main repo) which records the SHA1 of that submodule.

This is reflected in the reverse process (when you want to [*remove* a submodule from a Git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162000/6309))